# Is there an equivalent to webpacks css loader for using javasctipt modules?

Tags: javascript, css, module

B"H

If we want to move from using a bundler to using javascript modules in the browser.
How would we handle css?

Most bundlers have been handling css in addition to javascript for a while. With the added benefit of javascript being able to include the css it needs automatically without the calling script having to keep track of which css the module needs.

Is there a way to keep that working?